# Tools to generate UI from REST endpoint

Tags: jquery, rest, user-interface, wadl

Are there any tools which auto generate UI if WADL/REST endpoint is provided?

If there aren't what would be best way to understand the REST endpoint. Interpret the WADL and auto-generate using jquery would be good approach? Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I would love to know what kind of UI you want to automatically create, and what problem you're trying to solve with this.

Comment: Based on the REST Data it can be a table or a form. We would like to provide options for user to pick the UI.